# Mocking System class method using testng, mockito and powermock

Tags: mockito, testng, powermockito

I am currently writing tests to a legacy code which uses a function `System.getenv("some_environment_variable")`

I get a problem when I try to mock these variables by using mockito and powermock (used under testng framework)

What I did so far was

```
@BeforeClass
public void setup() {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(System.class);
    PowerMockito.when(System.getenv("hello")).thenReturn("world");
}

@Test
public void test() {
    assertEquals(System.getenv("hello"), "world");
}
```

But when I tried to run the code above i get the following error:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
>   when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
>   For example:
>       when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);
>
> Also, this error might show up because:
>
> 1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
>      Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
>      Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
> 2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.

So Iv'e read and saw that this error raised when trying to mock a method with mocking the class itself, but this is not the case here.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share your `maven dependencies` information as well so that I can try recreating your issue? I am currently having `NoClassDefFoundError` issues for `org/mockito/cglib/proxy/MethodInterceptor` and I am pretty sure its due to messed up dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After toying around with this for quite sometime, here's how I managed to do it.

In a nutshell, in order to get powermockito and TestNG to work with each other you have to do the following (quoting from the blog post whose link is shared below so that the answer is complete and will be useful even if the blog is not available at a later point in time)

1. **Configure TestNG to use the PowerMock object factory** : You can do this either via the attribute `object-factory` in your `<suite>` tag of your suite xml or via an `@org.testng.annotations.ObjectFactory` annotated method which returns the powermock's implementation of TestNG interface `org.testng.IObjectFactory` viz., `org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockObjectFactory` (or) by extending `org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockTestCase`
2. **Use `@PrepareForTest` to prepare your static class for being mocked by PowerMockito**

Please refer to [this](http://jivimberg.github.io/blog/2016/04/03/using-powermock-plus-testng-to-mock-a-static-class/) blog for more details.

Here's a working sample:

```
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.testng.IObjectFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.ObjectFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;

@PrepareForTest(System.class)
public class SampleTestClass {
    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(System.class);
        PowerMockito.when(System.getenv("hello")).thenReturn("world");
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertEquals(System.getenv("hello"), "world");
    }

    @ObjectFactory
    public IObjectFactory getObjectFactory() {
        return new org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockObjectFactory();
    }

}
```

I used the below dependencies for creating this sample

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-testng</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I find it terribly ugly to spend such amounts of workarounds to test such code. But well, when it is about testing some legacy code it might be the only choice here. But still ...

Comment: @GhostCat - I would be curious to know as to what you are referring to as workarounds. Are you referring to using Mocks in general ? If it hadn't been legacy code, we could have created an interface which when invoked would give out a environment variable and then inject an implementation that invokes `System.getEnv()` for production code and the tests could inject a fake object which returns back a hard coded value. That would have been a bit more straightforward. Atleast that's one way I could think of. But since its legacy code, I guess that luxury is not available.

Answer (score 0):

There is another JUnit library which may help you: [system-rules](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/#EnvironmentVariables), which will allow you to -- among other things -- set and restore environment variables.  It is used in conjunction with JUnit `@Rule`s