# PowerMock fails with JerseyTest

Tags: unit-testing, jersey, powermock, easymock

We're writing unit tests for a Jersey Java REST service using PowerMock. We have to use PowerMock because we use numerous static methods in a legacy system. We're using PowerMock with EasyMock. Whenever we try to inherit from JerseyTest, the whole framework fails.

It's a gradle based project, and the pertinent `build.gradle` lines are below.

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile group: 'org.easymock', name: 'easymock', version: '3.5.1'
testCompile group: 'org.easymock', name: 'easymockclassextension', version: '3.2'
testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-module-junit4', version: '1.7.3'
testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-easymock', version: '1.7.3'
```

We have a few EasyMock unit tests up and running, so we know our imports are working correctly. The problem is that since we're testing a Jersey web service, our unit tests inherit from JerseyTest. Writing a PowerMock unit test without inheriting from JerseyTest works fine. But when we try to inherit from JerseyTest, it all falls apart. Google failed us (apparently no one else who has written a Jersey web service has tried using PowerMock).

What we do is fairly straight-forward. This works:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class PowerMockTest {

    private final static String TARGET = "ourwebservice/";

    @Test
    public void testConfigurationGet() {
        // do stuff, but no Jersey web service calls
    }
}
```

Changing the class declaraction to inherit from JerseyTest, however:

```
public class PowerMockTest extends JerseyTest {
```

And we get a complete failure. We're using Eclipse as our IDE, and this is the error that displays in the JUnit window:

```
initializationError (0.000 s)
```

The Failure Trace window gives more details:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Inconsistent stackmap frames at branch target 38
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/ourcompany/ourproduct/rest/PowerMockTest.<init>()V @38: aload_1
Reason:
Type uninitializedThis (current frame, locals[1]) is not assignable to 'com/ourcompany/ourproduct/rest/PowerMockTest' (stack map, locals[1])
  Current Frame:
    bci: @24
    flags: { flagThisUninit }
    locals: { uninitializedThis, uninitializedThis, top, 'java/lang/Object' }
    stack: { 'java/lang/Object', 'java/lang/Object' }
  Stackmap Frame:
    bci: @38
    flags: { flagThisUninit }
    locals: { uninitializedThis, 'com/ourcompany/ourproduct/rest/PowerMockTest' }
    stack: { }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2a4c 1211 b800 1703 bd00 1912 1ab8 001e
    0x0000010: b800 244e 2db2 0028 a500 0e2a 01c0 002a
    0x0000020: b700 2ea7 0009 2bb7 0030 0157 a700 0301
    0x0000030: 3a05 2ab8 0036 b1                      
  Stackmap Table:
    append_frame(@38,Object[#14])
    chop_frame(@44,1)
    same_frame(@47)

    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.getTestMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:109)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.<init>(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:85)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.<init>(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:42)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit49RunnerDelegateImpl.<init>(PowerMockJUnit49RunnerDelegateImpl.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:172)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:48)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:108)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:71)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:36)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

We can't even step into the method to debug it; it fails before that (note, the test doesn't even actually do anything yet; we're just trying to get things set up first).

Anyone have any idea what's going on? Do we have some sort of configuration error? Do we have to switch to Mockito?

Comment: What about controlling the JerseyTest with composition, rather than inheritance?

Comment: I could give it a shot. I'll report on my results...

Comment: [For example](https://gist.github.com/psamsotha/0fe34f91edad715d09f1e09dd579d625)

Comment: Thanks for the example at the link. Unfortunately, that didn't work either. It blows up in much the same manner. :'(

Comment: I found something that helped. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45528317/issue-when-test-a-jersey-rest-service-using-powermock-with-jersey-test-testng) has some markup that helped another user with a similar issue: `@org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PowerMockIgnore({"javax.ws.*", "org.glassfish.*"})`. It fixed the barfing I was getting and things looked really promising. But it seems I can only return Strings. All other types result in errors. I recognize the error, but I already have the fix in place, but it still errors-out.