# PowerMock with Jersey, InternalServerErrorException error

Tags: rest, unit-testing, powermock, jersey-test-framework

We have a gradle Jersey project and we're trying to use PowerMock and EasyMock (and JUnit) for the unit tests because we have several static methods we need to mock. We finally got PowerMock working with Jersey (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48465607/powermock-fails-with-jerseytest)), but PowerMock will only allow our REST calls to return Strings. All other return types--like Lists, for example--result in an `InternalServerErrorException`. Full stack trace:

```
javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.convertToException(JerseyInvocation.java:1020)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:877)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$800(JerseyInvocation.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$3.call(JerseyInvocation.java:722)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:718)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:430)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:321)
    at com.company.project.sm.rest.PowerMockTest.aListTest(PowerMockTest.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:326)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:298)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:218)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:160)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:134)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:136)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:121)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

The REST calls in the unit tests work without PowerMock; they fail when run with PowerMock. We can't spot what we're doing wrong.

Here are examples of our unit tests (entire class):

```
// comment-out these two lines to turn off PowerMock
@org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PowerMockIgnore({"javax.ws.*", "org.glassfish.*"})
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class PowerMockTest {

    private JerseyTest jerseyTest;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        this.jerseyTest = new JerseyTest() {
            @Override
            protected Application configure() {
                return PowerMockTest.this.configure();
            }
        };
        this.jerseyTest.setUp();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        this.jerseyTest.tearDown();
    }

    public ResourceConfig configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(PowerMockTestResource.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void thisTestWorks() {

        String fooString = this.jerseyTest.target("test/string")
            .request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
            .get( String.class );

        assertNotNull( fooString );
    }

    @Test
    public void thisTestFails() {

        List<PowerMockStringWrapper> response = this.jerseyTest.target("test/list")
                                        .request( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
                                        .get( new GenericType<List<PowerMockStringWrapper>>() {} );

        assertNotNull( response );
    }
}
```

The `.get` line in `thisTestFails()` is the line the stack trace reports is failing.

As you can see, we're not even doing anything PowerMock-ey in our tests. The `PowerMockStringWrapper` is just a small class that wraps String, because Jersey (for some reason) can't return Lists of base Strings. Once again, both these unit tests work without PowerMock, but the second one fails as soon as we turn PowerMock on.

Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: Maybe something on the server side causing the error. But the exception is getting swallowed up. Try to register an `ExceptionMapper<Throwable>` with the `ResourceConfig`. You can print the stack trace in the mapper.

Comment: Thanks, tried that. No exception is getting "swallowed up" on the server-side (despite the 500 error). It just fails as always before, with the stack trace in the JUnit Failure Trace window.

Comment: I added a comment in the question pointing out the line that the failure trace says the problem occurs on.